# How do i write an application that converts digital signal into its respective note?

Tags: audio

In other words if a c6 played on a piano on a clean channel, the program is able to decode it. Im aware it gets rather complicated, but maybe not so much with a single tone.

Comment: wow, what a question... but you "just" have to measure the frequency of the wave... And BTW: It gets *really* complicated if it's more than a single, clean note - lots of manufacuturers have been working on that for decades, but so far with little success...

Comment: once analog audio has been sampled into its digital counterpart its a series of points on a curve typically stored as an integer array ... this time domain data needs to get sent into a Fourier Transform call to some library which will return the frequency domain representation of this input audio curve ... now instead of the X axis being time its now frequency ... where height at each frequency represents the strength at that frequency the strongest of which will be the freq ( note ) of your C6

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkGsMWi_j4Q # Discrete Fourier Transform - Simple Step by Step